# Calculating the time difference(in hours and minutes) using strtotime()

Tags: php, date, datetime

```
$time1 = strtotime('23:56');
$time2 = strtotime('00:21');
echo ($time1 - $time2)/60;
```

The expected o/p is `25`.But it returns `1415`;

If I change

`$time2= strtotime('24:21');`

It returns -`25` which is partially correct(since it returns negative ).

Can any one suggest me, some other function to calculate 
time difference in minutes.

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you [examine the contents of `$time1` and `$time2`](http://ideone.com/XpKL6W) to see what's going on?

Comment: Why would the expected result here be 25? The difference between 23:56 - 00:21 = 23:35 (that's 23 hours and 35 minutes or 1415 minutes).

Comment: 23:56 - 00:21 is **23**:35. 23*60+35 = 1415, so what you're getting is correct

Comment: How is PHP supposed to just _guess_ that you meant 00:21 _tomorrow_?

Comment: Yeah i did. Can you suggest a replacement for strotime in order to accurately calculate the time difference ..

Comment: @all, i know PHP is doing it correctly.So,What should be quickest solution to this problem, should i replace 00:21 to 24:21, instead of converting 1415 ?

Comment: @Vaibhav If the second is less than first one, add one day. I assume that second should always be greater than the first one.

Answer (score 12):

if you use strtotime with only a time it takes the current date so:

```
$time1 = strtotime('23:56');  // 2012-12-06 23:56
$time2 = strtotime('00:21');  // 2012-12-06 00:21
echo ($time1 - $time2)/60;
```

Answer (score 5):

This is because you are not specifying a day, so 00:21 is the start of today and 23:56 is the end of today

1415 being the 23 hours difference.

Answer (score 4):

Assume that `$time2` must be greater than or equal to `$time1`. Then adjust `$time2` accordingly:

**Example 1 -- same day**

```
$time1 = strtotime('00:21');
$time2 = strtotime('23:56');
if($time2 < $time1) {
    $time2 += 24 * 60 * 60;
}
echo ($time2 - $time1) / 60; // 1415
```

**Example 2 -- day rolls over**

```
$time1 = strtotime('23:56');
$time2 = strtotime('00:21');
if($time2 < $time1) {
    $time2 += 24 * 60 * 60;
}
echo ($time2 - $time1) / 60; // 25
```

Answer (score 2):

php's answer is correct, how should it know that you think about the next day? Just subtract your value from 1440 (Minutes in a day), then you'll have the desired result...

Answer (score 1):

The expected output is not `25`. You're subtracting an early time of day from a late time of day.  11:56 PM - 12:21 AM is almost 24 hours (or 1440 minutes).

Your result is `1415` which is exactly what's expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the timestamp of `$temp` and use date function

```
 $time1 = timestamp;
$time2 = timestamp;
$temp  = $time1 - $time2;

echo date("F j Y i:s",$temp);
```